# git pull to branch_1 and merge into current branch simultaneously

Tags: git, merge, git-checkout

I took a look around, but didn't see this exact question answered, so here I go:

```
git checkout master
git checkout -b release1
git checkout -b feature1
git checkout -b feature2
```

i do work on `feature1`, someone else does work on `feature2`, both are pushed to origin

```
git checkout -b feature1
git pull
git checkout -b feature2
git pull
```

Question 1: Can I pull the latest from origin of `feature1` and `feature2` to their respective local branches without having to check them out individually and pull them each separate?

Continuing along . . .

```
git checkout release1
git merge feature1
git merge feature2
```

Someone else does work on `feature2`.

Question 2: I want to merge the latest on origin `feature2` into my current `release1` branch without switching branches to pull it, then switching again to merge it. Is this possible?

Comment: what's the problem with switching branches? there's no other way to pull or merge than being on the branch you want to work with.

Comment: Thanks Charles. I just thought it would be slick to update a branch merge it, simultaneously.

Comment: please use @author so that he gets notified (I don't use it here because you'll be notified as being the poster)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way around (except extreme git hacking), merging commits of another branch, whether it is remote (`git pull`) or local (`git merge`), imply having the "destination" branch checked out.